# Passing controller variables or parameters to a Helper Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, helper

I have a HTML template which should change the body class in the application.rb template depending on some settings on the controller.

I know how to do that when I wanna change that from the view. I do this with something like:

```
# in view
<% layout_class("full", boxed: false) %>

# helper method
module TemplateHelper
  def layout_class(class_name="")
    content_tag("body", :id => "fluidGridSystem", :class => class_name) do
      yield
    end
  end
end
```

Forget the lines above!

## I wanna make that happen within the controller

```
# index_controller.rb
class IndexController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @layout_class = "hello"
  end
end

# app/helpers/template_helper.rb
module TemplateHelper

  def body_wrapper
    content_tag("body", :id => "fluidGridSystem", :class => @layout_class) do
      if some_logic # show <body> only
        yield
      else # add some more <div>'s
        blog_wrapper do
          yield
        end
      end
    end

    def blog_wrapper(inner="", outer="")
      content_tag("div", :class => outer) do
        content_tag("div", :class => inner) do
          yield
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

# application.rb
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <%= body_wrapper do %> # this part generates <body class="hello">
    <%= flash_messages %>
    <%= yield %>
  <% end %> # </body>
</html>
```

But `@layout_class` is not passed to the helper.

- How can I do that?
- Or is the view approach the better colution?
- Reason is that I wanna add breadcrumbs, and body classes dependent on the controller logic.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is your helper method's name is different to what you're calling?

I don't know about `body_wrapper`, but you're calling `layout_class` - two different methods. Why don't you try this:

```
#app/helpers/template_helper.rb
module TemplateHelper
  def layout_class 
    content_tag("body", :id => "fluidGridSystem", :class => @layout_class ) do
     yield
    end
  end
end

#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<body class="<%= layout_class(@layout_class) %>">
```

---

There are two other potential ways to do this:

**1. Change Layout**

If you only have certain criteria to change, you may wish to try:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
layout :layout

private

def layout
    if #your_logic
        "layout"
    else
        "other_layout"
    end
end
```

**2. Call `@layout_class` directly from view**

```
#app/views/layouts/application.rb
<body class="<%= @layout_class %>">
```

This will show the class if `@layout_class` is set, and will not publish the "class" attribute if it doesn't

Comment: Hi Rich, I have updated my post for a better explanation and also added the application.html.erb part. Please review that. I also removed the typo which you pointed out. I hope it's clearer now. Many thanks in advance